# Need a function to create a new variable on the first row, then replace a different variable with the new one (for many rows)

Tags: r

I have a dataset that has shows the substitutions in a basketball game. The first row of data has a variable 'lineupBefore' that tells us all 5 players who were on the court prior to the substitution.

```
df <- tibble(sub_num = c(1,2,3),
             player_out = c('player_5', 'player_4', 'player_3'),
             player_in = c('player_5', 'player_7', 'player_8'),
             lineupBefore = c('player_1, player_2, player_3, player_4, player_5',NA,NA)
             )
```

What I would like to accomplish is to fill the dataframe, with a new variable 'lineupAfter' that str_replaces the player_out for the player_in, then the next row pulls `lineupAfter` into the NA for `lineupBefore` then does the str_replace for that row of data.

The output would hopefully look like this.

```
df_after <- tibble(sub_num = c(1,2,3),
             player_out = c('player_5', 'player_4', 'player_3'),
             player_in = c('player_6', 'player_7', 'player_8'),
             lineupBefore = c('player_1, player_2, player_3, player_4, player_5','player_1, player_2, player_3, player_4, player_6','player_1, player_2, player_3, player_7, player_6'),
             lineupAfter = c('player_1, player_2, player_3, player_4, player_6', 'player_1, player_2, player_3, player_7, player_6', 'player_1, player_2, player_8, player_7, player_6')
)
```

I tried this but understand it won't work because I believe mutate works on a column at a time, and doesn't go back and forth.

```
 df_after <- df %>% 
  mutate(lineupAfter = str_replace(lineupBefore, player_out, player_in),
         lineupBefore = if_else(row_number() != 1, lag(lineupAfter), lineupBefore))
```

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Your `player_in` changes between `df` and `df_after`, I'm assuming your first `player_out` is supposed to be `"player_6"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since each row depends on the results *after* changing the row before it, we need to do a reduction using `Reduce` or `purrr::reduce`.

I prefer using list-columns as it provides clearer set-operations without the "risk" (not much risk here, admittedly) of regex.

```r
df %>%
  mutate(
    lineupBefore = strsplit(lineupBefore, "[, ]+"),
    lineupAfter = Reduce(function(prev, rn) c(setdiff(prev, player_out[rn]), player_in[rn]),
                         row_number(), init = lineupBefore[[1]], accumulate=TRUE)[-1], 
    across(starts_with("lineup"), ~ sapply(.x, toString))
  ) %>%
  as.data.frame()
#   sub_num player_out player_in                                     lineupBefore
# 1       1   player_5  player_6 player_1, player_2, player_3, player_4, player_5
# 2       2   player_4  player_7                                               NA
# 3       3   player_3  player_8                                               NA
#                                        lineupAfter
# 1 player_1, player_2, player_3, player_4, player_6
# 2 player_1, player_2, player_3, player_6, player_7
# 3 player_1, player_2, player_6, player_7, player_8
```

(I added `as.data.frame` at the end just to provide full strings on the console render, it is not required.)

Walk-through:

- `strsplit(.)` converts strings into a list-column, so now the first row is `c("player_1", "player_2", "player_3", "player_4", "player_5")` (a vector), and `lineupBefore` is a list of such vectors;
- `Reduce` does "something" on a value and a vector, then takes the results and operates on the next. Since we need to operate on multiple columns, we need the value to be the row number. The `init=` is the starting value, and on each call to the anon-function the `prev=` argument is the lineup and `rn=` is the row numbers (as provided using `row_number()`).
- the default behavior of `Reduce` is to return only the result at the very end; since we want all interim values, we add `accumulate=TRUE`, and since the result is 1 longer than the `row_number()` vector (the first element is the `init=` value, we don't want it), we `[-1]` remove the first.
- since the inner anon-function is doing set-ops (`setdiff` and `c`oncatenate), the order is not exactly as you portrayed, I hope this is not an issue.
- finally, I restore it to strings for you, assuming you really prefer to work with strings; I would likely keep it as a list-column, so you can remove `across(.)` if that's the case.

The same thing but using `stringr::str_replace`:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(
    lineupAfter = Reduce(function(prev, rn) stringr::str_replace(prev, player_out[rn], player_in[rn]),
                         row_number(), init = lineupBefore[[1]], accumulate=TRUE)[-1]
  ) %>%
  as.data.frame()
#   sub_num player_out player_in                                     lineupBefore
# 1       1   player_5  player_6 player_1, player_2, player_3, player_4, player_5
# 2       2   player_4  player_7                                             <NA>
# 3       3   player_3  player_8                                             <NA>
#                                        lineupAfter
# 1 player_1, player_2, player_3, player_4, player_6
# 2 player_1, player_2, player_3, player_7, player_6
# 3 player_1, player_2, player_8, player_7, player_6
```

Answer (score 2):

This is similar in concept to @r2evans’ solution, but uses `purrr::accumulate2()`, which can take two inputs rather than indexing by row number:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

df_after <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    lineupAfter = accumulate2(
      player_out, player_in, 
      \(lineup, p_out, p_in) str_replace(lineup, p_out, p_in),
      .init = lineupBefore[[1]]
    )[-1],
    lineupBefore = lag(lineupAfter, default = lineupBefore[[1]])
  )
```

Result:

```
## shorten "player_" to "p" for display purposes
#> mutate(df_after, across(!sub_num, \(x) str_replace_all(x, "player_", "p")))

# A tibble: 3 × 5
  sub_num player_out player_in lineupBefore       lineupAfter       
    <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     <chr>              <chr>             
1       1 p5         p6        p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 p1, p2, p3, p4, p6
2       2 p4         p7        p1, p2, p3, p4, p6 p1, p2, p3, p7, p6
3       3 p3         p8        p1, p2, p3, p7, p6 p1, p2, p8, p7, p6
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not an efficient workflow for many reasons but you could use a simple *for* loop:

```
df$lineupAfter <- NA_character_
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
  df$lineupAfter[i] <- with(df, sub(player_out[i], player_in[i], lineupBefore[i], fixed = TRUE))
  if (i == nrow(df)) break
  df$lineupBefore[i+1L] <- df$lineupAfter[i]
}
```